# new build Ubuntu won't install

Tags: system-installation

Just built a budget rig to install Ubuntu on, LTS 64bit version. Using an LGA 1155 celeron g1630 on an ECS Mobo and 4g ddr3 RAM on a 480w corsair PSU, 1 tb hdd. I went on my wife's PC to download the ubuntu version and stored it in a brand new thumb "flash" drive. Enter the bios and I can't seem to boot Ubuntu up for the life of me! Do I change the boot settings from window s 7 or others to manual? Because that didn't work! Do I change the boot priority to flash drive first because that didn't work. Is there a different way to go about ubuntu installation on a new rig?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem from the info provided you are trying to boot from a thumb drive with simply just Ubuntu on it.

You will need to make the thumb-drive bootable, and Ubuntu correctly installed onto the thumb-drive.

The easiest way to do this is use UUI. This will do all the command line hard-work for you in a flash.

Simply download UUI - Universal USB Installer, and follow the very simple GUI to install Ubuntu onto the thumb-drive. Simple as 1, 2, 3!

You may THEN boot from the drive and install Ubuntu with ease.

UUI Website: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/